# Computer Solving Lights On Game

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have made a game where a board of randomly lit squares are generated (0 is off and 1 is on) and the goal is to light up the entire board. Currently I have been using user input to win the game where when a square is clicked it inverts as well as its neighbors above, bellow, left, and right. Now I am trying to allow the computer to solve the game without user input, but my `choice` function in `evolve2d` does not work correctly. Currently it is producing the original list over and over again. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import time # provides time.sleep(0.5)
from csplot import choice
from random import * # provides choice( [0,1] ), etc.
import sys  # larger recursive stack
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000) # 100,000 deep

def runGenerations2d(L , x = 0,y=0):
    show(L)
    print( L )           # display the list, L
    time.sleep(.1)      # pause a bit
    newL = evolve2d( L )   # evolve L into newL
    print(newL)
    if min(L) == 1:
        #I like read outs to be explained so I added an extra print command.
        if x<=1: # Takes into account the possibility of a 1 click completition.
            print ('BaseCase Reached!... it took %i click to complete' % (x))
            print (x)
            done()#removes the need to input done() into the shell
        else:
            print ('BaseCase Reached!... it took %i clicks to complete' % (x))
            print (x)
            done()#removes the need to input done() into the shell
        return   
    x = x+1 # add 1 to x before every recusion
    runGenerations2d( newL , x,y )  # recurse

def setNewElement2d( L, i, j, x=0, y=0 ):
    if y==j and (i == x-1 or i == x+1 or i ==x):
        return 1-L[j][i] 
    elif x==i and (j == y-1 or j == y+1):  
        return 1-L[j][i] 
    else: 
        return L[j][i] 

def evolve2d( L ):    
    N = len(L)  # N now holds the size of the list
    x = choice (L)
    y = choice (L)
    return [[ setNewElement2d( L, i, j,x,y ) for i in range(N)]for j in range(N) ]
```

Comment: Why are you importing "choice" from csplot and then immediately blowing that away with a different import of "choice" from random? Secondly, I would generally recommend never to use `import *` since it can create ambiguous results. Also, why do you have `if x<=1` at all since in both the True and the False cases you are executing the same code.

Comment: Honestly, I'm having trouble decoding this. Recursion is a bear. I'm really just reacting to your comment that "choice" is not working. Tail recursion such as this can always be refactored into a loop - have you considered it?

Comment: Do you have two accounts, or are you and Xuvin both working on the same problem?

Comment: People thinking of answering should visit the following link, where the OP posted nearly the same question and, when answered, simply deleted it: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33073485/revisions